# AHK How to completely hide ApplicationFrameHost.exe window (such as Windows 10 Settings, Photos, Mail)

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried WinHide but it only hides the window and the taskbar icon remains.

| Before WinHide | After WinHide |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before WinHide] | [image: After WinHide] |

Here's my code:

```
WinHide, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ahk_exe ApplicationFrameHost.exe, Settings
MsgBox, Hidden but the taskbar icon remains
WinShow, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ahk_exe ApplicationFrameHost.exe, Settings
MsgBox, Shown
```